# To read the hex value of a .txt file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, hex

If I have some text file like abc.txt the I want to the hex value of that .txt file
like we see when we open notepad+ can click on hex...something like this

```
74 68 65 72 77 69 73 65 20 69 73 20 69 74 63 68    
therwise is itch

69 6e 27 20 66 6f 72 20 61 20 66 69 67 68 74 2e     
in' for a fight.
```

Now i want these hex values of individual letters.

I know how to read text by using `FileStream()` and `StreamReader()`.

But now want these hex values how can i get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("C:\\file.ext", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None));
reader.BaseStream.Position = 0x0;     // The offset you are reading the data from
byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(0x10); // Read 16 bytes into an array
reader.Close();
```

So assuming the input is `therwise is itch`:

```
string data_as_str = Encoding.Default.GetString(data); // Output: therwise is itch
string data_as_hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);      // Output: 74-68-65-72-77-69-73-65-20-69-73-20-69-74-63-68
```

Answer (score 4):

Open using `FileStream`, then use `Read` to get arrays of `byte`. For each element in the array convert to a hex pair with `byteVal.ToString("x2")` (use `X2` if you want uppercase hex).